# Avoid opening an new browser for every instance in Selenium Python

Tags: python, selenium, for-loop, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I got a Python Selenium project that does what I want (yay!) but for every instance it opens a new browser window. Is there any way to prevent that?

I've went through the documentation of Selenium but they refer to `driver.get(url)`. It's most likely because it's in the `for...loop` but I can't seem to get the URL to change with the `queries` and `params` if it's outside of the `for...loop`.

So, for example, I want to open these URLs:

- https://www.google.com/search?q=site%3AParameter1+%22Query1%22
- https://www.google.com/search?q=site%3AParameter2+%22Query1%22
- https://www.google.com/search?q=site%3AParameter3+%22Query1%22

etc..

```
from selenium import webdriver
import time
from itertools import product

params = ['Parameter1', 'Parameter2', 'Parameter3', 'Parameter4']

queries = ['Query1', 'Query2', 'Query3', 'Query4',]

for (param, query) in product(params,queries):
    url = f'https://www.google.com/search?q=site%3A{param}+%22{query}%22' # google as an example
    driver = webdriver.Chrome('G:/Python Projects/venv/Lib/site-packages/chromedriver.exe')
    driver.get(url)

#does stuff
```

Comment: Dont do this line "webdriver.Chrome(....)" -> This opens new driver

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are declaring your path to Chrome in the loop. Declare it once and reuse:

```
from itertools import product
from selenium import webdriver

params = ['Parameter1', 'Parameter2', 'Parameter3', 'Parameter4']

queries = ['Query1', 'Query2', 'Query3', 'Query4',]
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path='/snap/bin/chromium.chromedriver')

for (param, query) in product(params,queries):
    url = f'https://www.google.com/search?q=site%3A{param}+%22{query}%22'
    driver.get(url)
# driver.close()
```

Comment: I see, going to give it a try later today! Thanks for your fast response. Don't you have the use the `driver` in a function argument?

Comment: If you create a function, then you may need to pass `driver`. In this example - no need.

Comment: Legend! Thanks, will give it a shot after these 2 meetings ;)

Comment: Note `driver.close()`. You may need it in a loop, or not. It depends on what you want to do.